# Touch event (onClickListener) not triggered for recyclerView

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-recyclerview

In this i have added SetoNclicklistener for recyclerview itself but when i click the recycler view nothing gets triggered ..please help

Main Activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.view);





    getOverflowMenu();

    android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager loaderManager = getSupportLoaderManager();
    android.support.v4.content.Loader<Cursor> loader=loaderManager.getLoader(loader_id);
    if(loader!=null) {
        loaderManager.initLoader(loader_id, null, this);
    }
    else
    {
        loaderManager.restartLoader(loader_id,null,this);
    }
 recyclerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"touched",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
     }
 });


}
```

Recycler Adapter
`public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private   int total_items=0;
private Context context;
private Cursor lcursor;



public RecycleAdapter(Context mcontext,Cursor cursor) {
    context=mcontext;
    lcursor=cursor;

}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
    RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder=new RecyclerViewHolder((view));


    return recyclerViewHolder;


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
   if(!lcursor.moveToPosition(position)) {

       return;
   }
    String todo=(lcursor.getString(lcursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.Column.COLUMN_TODO_NAME)))+" "+
            (lcursor.getString(lcursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.Column.COLUMN_TODO)));
   String time=lcursor.getString(lcursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.Column.COLUMN_TODO_TIME));
    holder.item_desc.setText(todo);
    holder.item_date.setText(time);
    holder.itemView.setTag(lcursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.Column._ID));




}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return lcursor.getCount();
}


public  class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{

    private TextView item_desc,item_date;
    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        item_desc=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_desc);
        item_date=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_date);
    }






}


}
```

Comment: What you want to implement?

Comment: you are clicking the items in recycelrview not the recyclerView, set `onClickListener()` for the items.

Comment: Why do you want to set the OnClickListener for the entire view? Most apps will set listeners for individual views within a RecyclerView.

Comment: You want click for RecycleView or RecycleView item?.If you only want item click then  `holder.itemView.setOnClickListener`   will do.

Comment: I just want to click recyclerview not an item in it..

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
   if(!lcursor.moveToPosition(position)) {

    return;
 }
 String todo=(lcursor.getString(lcursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.Column.COLUMN_TODO_NAME)))+" "+
        (lcursor.getString(lcursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.Column.COLUMN_TODO)));
 String time=lcursor.getString(lcursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.Column.COLUMN_TODO_TIME));
holder.item_desc.setText(todo);
holder.item_date.setText(time);
    holder.itemView.setTag(lcursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.Column._ID));

holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // here you can perform any operation on perticuler view  
  }
}
}
```

you will get position of view

Comment: Thanks.works like charm..but it seems a listener is added for every item in the view if i has 1000 items in the list , 1000 listeners will be implemented ,.is there another way

Comment: Recyclerview have Lazy Loading functionality as well as it will create only reference of listener, so you can add N number it will not effect your performance .

Comment: Thanks for the response @ Rahul chaube

Answer (score 0):

try this :

use a custom `RecyclerItemClickListener` to get the click event

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(getApplicationContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    // TODO Handle item click
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"touched",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;

                }
            })
    );
```

Now define the class like:

```
 import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

For details see this link: http://sapandiwakar.in/recycler-view-item-click-handler/

Comment: There is a error in below code : parameter expects android.widget.Adapterview<> but a view is provided

Comment: in which line...?